# Charged particle accelerate between charged plate

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, particle-accelerators

I have an electron that travel with a velocity v, and kinetic energy Ek.
At some point it enter a region between two charged plate where there is an electric field that accelerate it.
So the variation in kinetic energy is equal to variation in potential energy, with the total energy conserved.
But when the electron go out of that region, has a velocity greater than when it entered so now has greater kinetic energy.
So how the total energy is conserved during the entire process?

Comment: The power supply generating (creating) the potential difference supplies the additional power.

Comment: @JonCuster That wouldn't explain it if the electron enters the space between the plates of a charged capacitor that is not connected to a voltage source. Check out the link I provided. I think you'll agree this is a duplicate of that link.

Answer (score 0):

Here, we provided external force field (electric), which caused our change in kinetic energy.

Remember: The total energy of a system remains conserved if: $$\sum F_{\text{external}}=0$$

But here as mentioned in question: $$\vec F_{\text{external}}=m_e\vec E$$
So total energy of our electron system changes.

Change in velocity or kinetic energy can be calculated with help of work-energy theorem
$$\frac{1}{2}m_ev_f^2-\frac{1}{2}m_ev_i^2=m\int\vec E\cdot d\vec r$$
Hope it helped you out!

Comment: Ok,  but the total energy of a particle is conserved when it moves in a conservative field. So If this is true, when it enter the region between the capacitor, before it has not potential energy, but just when it enter it has also a potential energy...... and same when it leaves, or is potential energy a "fake energy" in a way that it has a mean only when there is a field?